# fill nested std::map with insert operator

Tags: dictionary, insert, nested

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
map<int, map<string, int> > mapa;

// way A
mapa[10]["aaa"] = 20;

// way B -> Compilation Error
pair<int, pair<string, int> > par(10, make_pair("aaa", 20));
mapa.insert(par);


return 0;
}
```

I know that "way A" of populating the map works.
I want to use "way B" but it throw a compilation Error:
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map, int>::map(const std::pair, int>&)’

How can I populate the nested map with insert operator.

Pd: I don't use [] operator because it requires the default constructor to be defined which I don't have since I am using time_period objects from Boost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the type of your map is `map of (int -> map of (string -> int))` but you are trying to insert an entry of type `map of (int -> pair (string, int))`. A `pair` is not a `map`, thus the error.

**EDIT**:

According to [the documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/), a call to map's `[]` operator is equivalent to a series of other operations:

> mapped_type& operator[] (const key_type& k);
>
> A call to this function is equivalent to:
> (*((this->insert(make_pair(k,mapped_type()))).first)).second

so in your case, the call `mapa[10]["aaa"] = 20;` is equivalent to:

```
(*(( (*((mapa.insert(make_pair(10,map<string, int>()))).first)).second
  .insert(make_pair("aaa",20))).first)).second
```

but I believe if either key `10` or `aaa` exist, no element will be inserted in the map. I suggest you read the docs thoroughly and test for the expected behavior.

Comment: yes you are right. I understand what is the compilation error. What I would like to know is how can I do something similar to "the way A" but using the insert operator instead the [] operator.

Comment: It's actually a little more complex because the key might exist. If it does, the value, i.e., the map, exists and you have to update it. If not, you have to create the map.